# Determinant of symmetric p-diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is there a simple method to compute the determinant of the following matrix

$A =\begin{bmatrix} d_1 & a & 0 & b & 0 &c &0 &0\\
a & d_2 & a & 0 & b & 0 & c & 0\\
0 & a & d_3 & a & 0 & b & 0 & c\\
b & 0 & a & d_4 & a & 0 & b & 0\\
0 & b & 0 & a & d_5 & a & 0 & b\\
c & 0 & b & 0 & a & d_6 & a & 0\\
0 & c & 0 & b & 0 & a & d_7 & a\\
0 & 0 & c & 0 & b & 0 & a &d_8
\end{bmatrix}$